# Cloudfront query strings not logging

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway

i have set up a cloudfront distribution to deal with my image resizing for an app.

I have my image resize function sitting in AWS Lambda, with An API gateway call wrapped around it. In order to call this function the following url is used:

```
/images?url=&width=&height=
```

and the example:

```
/images?height=300&width=300&url=smodlEMvQc
```

When i add this onto the end of my cloudfront URL as follows:

```
examplecloudfront.net/images?height=300&width=300&url=smodlEMvQc
```

The query strings never appear in the Popular Objects which indicates the urls are not be cached.

[image]
I have ticketed the forward query string option and so it should be showing the query string inclusive url in the popular items as I have tested the same urls many times without any success

Comment: *"The query strings never appear in the Popular Objects which indicates the urls are not be cached."*  Well, no... it only indicates that they are not "popular."  Popularity is request frequency, nothing to do with caching.  A popular object can have 0.0% cache hits and still appear in the list. If you are trying to determine whether an object is served from the cache, read the `X-Cache:` response header.  What problem are you actually trying to solve?  Cache hit ratios?  Performance? Higher than expected number of back-end requests?

Comment: Since my prior comment, I did some testing on a CloudFront distribution which forwards query strings and has very little traffic, so it was easy to make test requests appear.  I have verified that the query strings were received by the back-end but **the query strings are not included in the URL on the popular objects report**.  It sounds like you are seeing normal behavior.  If you want to track by object, you'll need to modify your design to include more information in the actual path, e.g. `/images/smodlEMvQc?height=300&width=300` or even `/images/smodlEMvQc/300/300`.

Comment: thanks dude. I am very new to cloudfront as you can guess. That answers my question.

Comment: Okay, excellent... So, your question is essentially why the popular objects report doesn't treat variations in the query strings as "different" objects?  I will edit your question accordingly and write up my comments into an answer, along with a citation of some ambiguous documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness.
The query strings will appear in cloudfront logs.
Enable them for the cloudfornt distribution that you are using from the AWS console.
This will direct the logs into an S3 bucket.
The logs are CSV files that show the URL and the query strings.